# Question regarding expression for speed of a transverse wave in a string?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves, continuum-mechanics

> How to prove the expression for speed of transverse wave in a string
>   that is :- $$ v= \sqrt{\frac Tμ }$$ Without loss of mathematics rigor,
>   that is without using infinitesimals or differentials in the realm of
>   standard analysis?

Here,

T is tension on string,

$\mu$ is mass per unit length of a uniform density string.

Comment: Can you explain what you don't like about the standard derivation?

Comment: FWIW *non-standard* analysis, which is based on the explicit notion that infinitesimals really are numbers, is a much simpler model for translating physics into math than the limit-based definitions of "standard analysis."

Comment: @Knzhou The use of differential , that is to take a small element, what is small formally, if you can make that proof more rigorous maybe through epsilon delta or something else I would be grateful.

Comment: @alephzero I am not acquainted with non standard analysis till now, but I think the formalization in classical mechanics took place way before the birth of non standard analysis that is before 1975 , so I hope there should be some formal solution of my referred problem, if you can write an answer giving a formal solution I would be grateful.